# Why can't I pass variables via URL in PHP?

Tags: php, html, href

Given this URL:

```
 <a href="abs.php?id=<?php echo $f1 ;?>" >Edit</a>
```

Why can't I pass the variable $f1 to next PHP file?

Comment: Please pay more attention when asking a question and put more effort into it.

Comment: How you mean the next php file. Include/require or a next http request?

Comment: do your $f1 variable contains any id ? are you able get it directly before passing  ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

On the next page you would need to:

```
$f1 = $_GET['id'];
```

Answer (score 0):

Try like

```
<a href="newpage.php?id=<?php echo $f1;?>">NeXt PaGe</a>
```

and in the new page GET that id from url with

```
echo "The Id is ".$_GET['id'];
```

Answer (score 0):

Use this :-

```
 <a href="somepage.php?id=<?php echo $varname;?>">Click</a>
```

**EDIT :**

You are passing it correctly you need to access it on that page using this:-

```
$varname = $_GET['id'];
```

Answer (score 0):

If you want to pass variables to other PHP files consider [$_GET](http://php.net/manual/en/reserved.variables.get.php) variables, [$_POST](http://php.net/manual/en/reserved.variables.post.php) variables, [$_SESSION](http://php.net/manual/en/reserved.variables.session.php) variables, and/or [$_COOKIE](http://php.net/manual/en/reserved.variables.cookies.php) variables. If you want to use `href` then $_GET variables can easily be passed by simply modifying the link i.e:

```
<a href="page.php?var=$f1">Page</a>
```

On the following page (in this case page.php) you can access this variable by simply doing:

```
$var = $_GET['var'];
```